# How to build an Unified Authenfication and Authorization for all apps?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Consider that we want to build unified authentication and authorization for all our applications using AWS Cognito and a Single User pool. Each Admin User in the User Pool can create an organization and invite members to that organization with a specific Group. Each Group (e.g., admin, manager, IT or any other group) can have access to a set of applications, and each service or application has a set of permissions (roles).

What we need to determine in the applications is which roles the user has per service so that we can decide if the user can access features A and B. For example, if the user logs in and uses our application, such as Application A, we need to know which permissions the user has for this instance of Application A.

How can we resolve this? Could the Keycloak organization plugin help, or is there another approach that could be considered?